# 5pm previous day to 5pm today records group by to today date oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement where I have to identify whether a record is new or modified.

We are storing both new and modified records in the same table with the latest time stamp, and users can update the records any time, but we generate the report at 5pm once daily. If a record is created within the past 24 hours (i.e 5pm previous day to 5pm today), since the report generates at 5pm we have to treat that record as new even tough it was modified many times within the report window time. If a record was created more than 24 hours ago and was modified within the last 24 hours, then we have to treat as Modified.

I have written the query, but I need it to group 5am to 5pm , I am not sure how to do it, anyone please help !

```
select emp_id,
       case 
       when count(emp_id) <=1
       then 'New'
       else 'Modified'
       END as status
from   (
  select emp_id,
         emp_status,
         trunc(last_updated) as last_updated
  from employee
) 
group by emp_id,
         emp_status,
         trunc(last_updated)
order by last_updated)
group by emp_id
order by emp_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtract 17 hours from the time before truncating and then group on that:

```sql
select emp_id,
       case 
       when count(emp_id) <=1
       then 'New'
       else 'Modified'
       END as status
from   (
  select emp_id,
         emp_status,
         trunc(last_updated - INTERVAL '17' HOUR) as last_updated
  from employee
) 
group by emp_id,
         emp_status,
         last_updated
order by last_updated
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that it's 17 because 5pm is the 17th hour of the day in a 24-hour day.